# How to count elements in a list and return a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of

```
L = ['hello', 'hello', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello']
```

I want to count how many `'hello'` and `'hi'` in the list. So that the result is `'hello': 4`, `'hi': 1`.

How would I implement this result in dictionary form? My professor hasn't gone over this yet, so I'm not sure how to convert from list to dictionary.

Comment: did you hear about `Counter` ?

Comment: That's probably not in the spirit of the homework.

Comment: You'll have to show us some attempt at solving this, as SO isn't a homework completion service.

Comment: I'm not asking for a code answer though. I'm just asking to see if there are any built-in functions (for example Counter, like Avinash mentioned above).

Comment: some redundance using dict comprehension, but it could be `d = {itm:L.count(itm) for itm in L}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using no external modules and only the `count`, although there would be some redundancy using dict comprehension:

```
d = {itm:L.count(itm) for itm in set(L)}
```

If you are allowed to use external modules and do not need to implement everything on your own, you could use Python's [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which is delivered through the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from collections import defaultdict

word_list = ['hello', 'hello', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello']

d = defaultdict(int)
for word in word_list:
    d[word] += 1

print(d.items())
```

Giving you:

```
dict_items([('hi', 1), ('hello', 4)])
```

---

EDIT:
As stated in the comments you could use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) like this, which would be easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from collections import Counter

word_list = ['hello', 'hello', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello']

c = Counter(word_list)

print(c)
```

Giving you:

```
Counter({'hello': 4, 'hi': 1})
```

Comment: [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, its not a bad answer, just a different answer

Comment: Your first answer was exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: -1: `{itm:L.count(itm) for itm in L}` simply erases the dict key with the updated count until the final unique list value of duplicates. Wasteful and slow. You should do `{itm:L.count(itm) for itm in set(L)}` so that the count step is only done once per unique entry in the list.

Comment: @thewolf: This was not part of my answer, but added by David Zemens. I updated my answer due to your comment. Thanks for this improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def how_many(li): return Counter(li)
... 
>>> how_many(['hello', 'hello', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello'])
Counter({'hello': 4, 'hi': 1})
```

Or, you can do:

```
>>> li=['hello', 'hello', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello']
>>> {e:li.count(e) for e in set(li)}
{'hi': 1, 'hello': 4}
```

Or, you can do:

```
>>> di={}
>>> for e in li:
...    di[e]=di.get(e, 0)+1
... 
>>> di
{'hi': 1, 'hello': 4}
```